# how to use vue to develop chrome extension based on mainfest v3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I used vue to develop chrome extension based on mainfest v2, now I want to upgrade mainfest v2 to v3. But, popup html is empty. vue is not work. how to solve this problem?

html code:

```
<div id="app">
</div>

<script src="vue.js">
```

html render:

```
<!---->
```

Comment: have you read and understood all the documentation regarding upgrading v2 to v3 manifest? the fact that you are showing 2 html elements and think that's enough for anyone to guess what you've done wrong is the issue

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it. Mainfest v3 blocks to use unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval. so vue cdn is not work. change to vue-cli way and use this cmd to build：

```
npm run build --no-unsafe-inline
```